# Android Package Name With 2 Parts Instead of 3

Tags: android, google-play

Might there be any issues in having a 2 part package name rather than the prescribed 3 part **com.example.appname**?

For instance, my app and company name are both named *adamsapp*. Ie:the package name would be **app.adamsapp**.

I do not see any documentation from Android or the Play Store that warn against such use of a package name. I'm currently using this convention in both Android Studio and Firebase without any warning or error messages.

Comment: I think the only issue here is uniqueness.  If you can publish with `app.adamsapp`, _and_ you're certain that you won't have collisions with yourself later, when publishing other apps of your own, then go ahead and use it.

Comment: No, there won't be any issue from Google's side, you can use any package name... For e.g. WhatsApp uses com.whatsapp which is also 2 part! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id), You can use application id as follows

- It must have at least two segments (one or more dots).
- Each segment must start with a letter.
- All characters must be alphanumeric or an underscore [a-zA-Z0-9_].

This means you can also use 2 part package name like **app.adamsapp** in your application. There will be no problem except uniqueness. Anyway, due to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36989234), you cant use **_** as starting of the package name